# can not log in with administrator?

Tags: php

what is wrong if my code or my database?

my code

```
    if(isset($login)){
        if($sbg=='administrator'){
            $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM administrator WHERE email='$email' AND password='$pass'");
            $rows= mysql_num_rows($login);
            if($rows==0){
                $data = mysql_fetch_array($login);
                $_SESSION['login']      = true;
                $_SESSION['nama']       = $data['nama'];
                $_SESSION['email']      = $data['email'];
                $_SESSION['password']          = $data['password'];
            }else{
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have to change

```
if($rows==0)
```

with

```
if($rows>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you put your code in wrong if.

```
if($rows!=0){
                $data = mysql_fetch_array($login);
                $_SESSION['login']      = true;
                $_SESSION['nama']       = $data['nama'];
                $_SESSION['email']      = $data['email'];
                $_SESSION['password']          = $data['password'];
            }else{
```

Comment: ada yg salah dengan kodingmu brarti.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($login)){
        if($sbg=='administrator'){
            $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM administrator WHERE email='$email' AND password='$pass'");
            $rows= mysql_num_rows($login);

            if($rows>0){
                $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($login);
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['login']      = true;
                $_SESSION['nama']       = $data['nama'];
                $_SESSION['email']      = $data['email'];
                $_SESSION['password']          = $data['password'];
            }else{
}
```

you can just echo $rows to know if has some result if $rows shows 0 or nothing please check your mysql query.